# C++: Instantiate boost::thread in header

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, constructor, boost-thread

I am trying to run a thread from the moment when a class is instantiated.

The class has a header file:

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
....
class test
{
public:
....
boost::thread worker(doWork); --->how should this be declared?
...
}
```

And in the class methods, I implemented the function doWork () that should be called in the thread "worker".

```
...
void doWork()
{
while(1)
{
std::cout<<"hello";
}
}
....
```

Where should I instantiate the boost::thread to run the thread as long as the class "test" is instantiated?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You would initialise it in the constructor:

```
test::test() : worker(doWork) {}
```

Although you hint that it might be a member function; in which case you'll need to bind it to the object to call the member on:

```
worker([this]{doWork();})                // C++11
worker(boost::bind(&test::doWork, this)) // Old-school
```